# A non-rational variety with a full exceptional collection?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, open-problems, derived-categories, coherent-sheaves, projective-varieties

Does there exist a smooth non-rational projective variety whose bounded derived category of coherent sheaves admits a full exceptional collection? I could not find any examples in the literature (for instance projective spaces and intersections of quadrics, which admit full exceptional collections, are rational).

Comment: Perhaps this question should count as an "open problem".

Comment: @LeoAlonso is it? I did not know it. If you could post a link to a paper where it is stated to be an open problem,  I would accept it as an answer.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not aware of such a reference. In fact I can't figure out any example. On the other hand, you have a full description of the derived category of Abelian varieties, though not through an exceptional collection (if I'm not mistaken).

Comment: Bondal and Polishchuk's "Homological properties of associative algebras: the method of helices." shows that a variety with a full exceptional collection of length $\dim X+1$ must be a fano variety.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Rationality of a variety with a full exceptional collection is a well-know folklore conjecture. In some form a similar open question is mentioned in the paper of Brown and Shipman "The McKay Correspondence, Tilting, and Rationality".